# Extract multiple sections of string with the same delimiters in R

Tags: r, string, pdf, extract

Very new to R here!
I need to extract certain parts of string datas that appear between two delimiters (always the same 2).

In the sample provided below, the delimiters (left = this statement is not part of the regulations, right = personne-ressource) appear twice but in other files they could appear 20 times.

I would like to create a dataframe where every different text segments between those 2 delimiters are extracted and put into a different row.

Thanks in advance

left delimiter: this statement is not part of the regulations

right delimiter: personne-ressource

text sample:

regulatory impact analysis statement 
(this statement is not part of the regulations.) issues 
the deadline for submitting an application for compensation under the introduced forest pest compensation regulations (ifpcr), made pursuant to the plant protection act (the act), has expired. this means that affected landowners in the regulated area within the cities of mississauga, ontario and toronto, ontario, who received a notice to dispose with respect to affected trees on their property, resulting from a detection of infestation of the asian longhorn beetle (a non-native forest pest) in august 2013 are not eligible for compensation. these persons have suffered similar losses to persons (tree owners) who had trees on their properties affected by this pest as a result of previous infestations of the pest. not amending the ifpcr could also place at risk the pest management strategy of eradication for this invasive pest. 
personne-ressource 
marcel dawson
gestionnaire national
produits forestiers, division de la protection des 
végétaux
agence canadienne d’inspection des aliments 59, promenade camelot
ottawa (ontario)
k1a 0y9
téléphone : 613-773-7265
télécopieur : 613-228-6626
courriel : marcel.dawson@inspection.gc.ca 
contact 
marcel dawson
national manager
forest products, plant protection division canadian food inspection agency
59 camelot drive
ottawa, ontario
k1a 0y9
telephone: 613-773-7265
fax: 613-228-6626
email: marcel.dawson@inspection.gc.ca 
 (this statement is not part of the regulations.) issues 
the recreational use of 2c-phenethylamines and related substances (i.e. salts, derivatives, isomers and salts of derivatives and isomers of 2c-phenethylamines) has been on the rise in north america and across europe over the past decade. considered designer drugs, these substances are produced at a rapid pace and are readily available for sale on the internet and at raves, nightclubs and head shops. 
non-fatal and fatal effects from 2c-phenethylamines and related substances have been reported internationally in the media, and in scientific journals. reported adverse effects include chills, nausea, anxiety, confusion, 
personne-ressource 
denis arsenault
direction générale de la santé environnementale et de la 
sécurité des consommateurs
santé canada
immeuble principal de statistique canada 150, promenade du pré tunney
ottawa (ontario)
k1a 0t6
courriel : ocs_regulatorypolicy-bsc_

Comment: Please show us some sample data, what you are trying to match/extract, and the output you expect.

Comment: # datas are entire pdfs so let's use the following example
x<-as.character("Hello, my name is mat and I suck with R, goodbye. Hello, my name is Hector and I'm pretty good with R, goodbye")

# I want to extract the multiple parts of text between the delimiters "Hello" (on the left) and "goodbye" (on the right)
# What I would like is that the multiple extractions appear in a seperate row in a new dataframe 
# Like such (I think)

# [1] , my name is mat and I suck with R, 
# [2] , my name is Hector and I'm pretty good with R,

Answer (score 0):

This question is more tricky than it appears.  This solution first splits your string of sentences into a vector of individual sentences.  Then it uses `str_match` from the `stringr` package to repeatedly apply a regex to each sentence.  Here is the regex I used:

```
Hello.*?\\s+(.*?)[^\\w]?\\s+goodbye
```

This worked fairly well with your data and also another sentence I tested.  In any case, hopefully this answer points your in the right direction even if you need to tweak the regex again later on.

```
require(stringr)

x <- as.character("Hello, my name is mat and I suck with R, goodbye. Hello, my name is Hector and I'm pretty good with R, goodbye.  Hello stuff goodbye.")
result <- str_match(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\.")), "Hello.*?\\s+(.*?)[^\\w]?\\s+goodbye")[, 2]
result

[1] "my name is mat and I suck with R"            
[2] "my name is Hector and I'm pretty good with R"
[3] "stuff"
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Me again... I think I spoke to soon... If a understand correctly the 1st part (class(strsplit(x, "\\.")) splits the string in parts (i.e. sentences) using the dot (.). While the 2nd part (str_match) extract the text between Hello and goodbye IF they appear in the SAME created sentence. In the data we have, delimiters are 2 sentences that appear at the start and end of the section we want to extract. Sorry, my example (x) was oversimplified.

Comment: Update your _question_ (NOT another bloated comment) with your actual data.